# Unable to return differnet layout for different rows in listview android, without using view holder

Tags: android

Data flow is proper and I can see values in logs for rows, but my views are not visible on screen. Can someone please look into this code. Not sure why my views are not showing up on screen.

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Message message = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            if (message.getImagePath().isEmpty()) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_text_item, parent, false);

                if (message.getSender().equalsIgnoreCase("alpha")) {
                    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                    text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    text.setText(message.getText());
                } else {
                    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                    text.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    text.setText(message.getText());
                }
            } else {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_image_item, parent, false);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(message.getImagePath()).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
            }
        }
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
```

message_image_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

message_text_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks

Comment: What value returning from `getCount(),getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(int position)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not reusing your inflated view. You should do as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // check the view creation
    if (convertView == null) {
        // inflate your view here
    } else {
        // reuse the view inflated
    }
    // set the text, image, etc.
    return convertView; // return it
}
```

From your code, you might choose to switch to a `ViewType` condition. This will allow you to get the two differents layouts. Beside, using a `ViewHolder` could be better. Here's the implementation:

```
private final static ROWTYPE_WITH_TEXT = 0;
private final static ROWTYPE_WITH_IMAGE = 1;

private class ViewHolder {
    private TextView text;
    private ImageView imageView;
}

...
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() { return 2; }

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return ((Message) getItem(position)).getImagePath().isEmpty()
            ? ROWTYPE_WITH_TEXT : ROWTYPE_WITH_IMAGE;
    // if the item in the list of messages contains
    // an image path, then choose the row ROWTYPE_WITH_IMAGE
}

...
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    int rowtype = getItemViewType(position); // select the rowtype

    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder(); // init the viewholder
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); // init the inflater

        // select the specific layout
        if (rowtype == ROWTYPE_WITH_TEXT) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_text_item, null);
            holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);

        } else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_image_item, null);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        }

        view.setTag(holder); // keep the existing view
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag(); // reuse the view
    }

    Message message = getItem(position); // get the message

    // from the rowtype, set the elements (texts, images, etc)
    if (rowtype == ROWTYPE_WITH_TEXT)
        if (message.getSender().equalsIgnoreCase("alpha")) {
            holder.text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            holder.text.setText(message.getText());
        } else {
            holder.text.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            holder.text.setText(message.getText());
        }
    } else {
        Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(message.getImagePath())
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imageView);
    }

    return convertView; // return it
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as per your code position variable is not accessible in getView?
Error here - Message message = getItem(position); 


Also in here
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (messages.get(position).getImagePath().isEmpty())

messages dont have get method.
message class only has   private String sender;
    private String text;
    private String imagePath;
    private String emoticon;

Comment: @user7327850 yes, thanks for the position variable. Anyway, `messages.get()` was an example, it's the same as retrieve your object from `getItem`. I change it, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you are a super code .... with little tweaks things are working .. awesome..:) thanks again